# Error in round(n, digits = digits): non-numeric argument to mathematical function when printing svyCreateTableOne

Tags: r

I have been trying to work on IPTW using the Lalonde dataset. The codes are all working well until I tried to print the svyCreateTableOne, which would tell me there's an error:

> error in round(n, digits = digits): non numeric argument to mathematical function.

Here is my code:

```
install.packages("Matching")
install.packages("ipw")
install.packages("survey")
install.packages("MatchIt")
library(tableone)
library(Matching)
library(ipw)
library(survey)
library(MatchIt)
data(lalonde)


#Fixing the data
age<-as.numeric(lalonde$age)
black<-as.numeric(lalonde$race=='black')
hispan<-as.numeric(lalonde$race=='hispan')
white<-as.numeric(lalonde$race=='white')
educ<-as.numeric(lalonde$educ)
nodegree<-as.numeric(lalonde$nodegree)
married<-as.numeric(lalonde$married)
re74<-lalonde$re74
re75<-lalonde$re75
re78<-lalonde$re78
treat<-as.numeric(lalonde$treat)
mydata<-cbind(age,black,hispan,educ,nodegree,married,re74,re75,re78,treat)
mydata<-data.frame(mydata)

xvars<-c("age","educ","black","hispan", "married","nodegree","re74","re75")

#table1 
table1<-CreateTableOne(vars=xvars,strata="treat", data=mydata, test=FALSE)
print(table1,smd=TRUE)
undebug(print)
#Propensity Scores
psmodel<-glm(treat ~ age + educ + black + hispan + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
             family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(psmodel)

#value of propensity score for each subject
ps<-predict(psmodel,type="response")

#create weights
weight<-ifelse(treat==1,1/(ps),1/(1-ps))

#apply weights to data
weighteddata<-svydesign(ids = ~ 1, data =mydata, weights = ~weight)

#weighted table 1
weightedtable <- svyCreateTableOne(vars = xvars, strata="treat", data = weighteddata,
                                   test = TRUE)

#show table with SMD
print(weightedtable,smd = TRUE)
```

I've made sure that everything is numeric but the problem still persists. I've looked around for answers as well but nothing seems to help with my case. Can someone help please? Thank you!

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone/issues/83) may be helpful to review.